# Problem on solving congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I want to find $x$ in this equation for known positive integer values  $a$, $b$ and $m$.
$$a-bx+2^{6x+1}\equiv0\ \pmod{m}$$
Is the number of solutions for $x$ finite? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot see anything better than brute search.

Comment: $2^{6x+1}$ is periodic modulo $m$. Maybe we don't need to apply brute force. Is number of solutions finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a solution, then $u+km\phi(m)$ is also a solution , if m is odd.

Proof : $$a-b(u+km\phi(m))+2^{6(u+km\phi(m))+1} \equiv a-bu+2^{6u+1}*2^{6km\phi(m)}
\equiv a-bu+2^{6u+1}\equiv 0\ mod\ (\ m\ )$$
for odd m

For even $m$, the equation $2^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1\ (\ mod\ m\ )$ does not hold and
 carmichaels function might help.

So, if there is a solution, there are infinite many, if m is odd.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for my late reply. I had some exams in last few days.

Comment: No problem at all.